# Intercept "file:" scheme requests in WebView

Tags: android, android-webview, file-uri

I load **JS** code into `WebView`. This **JS** code requests some files using `file:` scheme uri. Those files are stored encrypted and I want to decrypt them inside Java code in time **JS** module requests them. I know that if those requests would be through `http:` scheme then I could setup local http server and pass decrypted content to **JS** module through it. Is there any way to pass decrypted content to **JS** module using `file:` scheme uri?

Comment: At a minimum you need the encryption key, do you have it.

Comment: Sure. I need a way to intercept request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `WebViewClient` subclass with an override for `shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)` and attach it to your `WebView`:

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {

        if ("file".equals(request.getUrl.getScheme())) { // plus your other conditions, of course

            String mimeType = ... // your mime type
            String encoding = ... // your character encoding
            ...

            InputStream data = ... // open stream to your decrypted file data
            return new WebResourceResponse(mimeType, encoding, data);

        } else {
            return null;  // tell WebView to handle it
        }
    }
});
```